# Is it possible to use a common remote validation check in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

To hvae remote validation you do the following in your view model:

```
public class ViewModelOne {
   [Required]
   [Remote("CheckStringIsRed", "RemoteValidationController", ErrorMessage = "It's not red.")]
   public string BgColour { get; set; }
}
```

and then have an action in a controller somewhere:

```
public JsonResult CheckStringIsRed(string BgColour) {
    return Json(BgColour == "Red");
}
```

but say I want to perform the same validation elsewhere so:

```
public class ViewModelOne {
    [Required]
    [Remote("CheckStringIsRed", "RemoteValidationController", ErrorMessage = "It's not red.")]
    public string SomeColour { get; set; }
}
```

Note how the property name is now **SomeColour** which means the call to the orginal CheckStringIsRed() will fail. So is there any way to reuse CheckStringIsRed() considering that the parameter names are different? I only want to write the validation once and use it on may properties.

Comment: Short answer - No. The `RemoteAttribute` adds `data-val` attributes which `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` uses to add rules to `jquery.validate.js` based on the name of the property. You would have to implement you own ajax call in order to achieve want you want.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Bummer.... If you want to post that as an answer I will accept.

Comment: Out of interest, your class names suggest you are following best practice and using view models, so why not just use a common property name?

Comment: @StephenMuecke My actual use case is to validate whether a boolean propery is true. Said boolean property can have many various names. My example with a string was purely illustrative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its not possible. The `RemoteAtribute` generates a `ModelClientValidationRule` which is used by the `HtmlHelper` to add `data-val-*` attributes, which are in turn read by `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` to add a rule to the jquery validator based on the name of the property.

You options include

- using the same property name across various view models or
- delete the attribute and make you own ajax call. For example

```cs
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.somePropertyName, new { @class = "validatecolor" })
<span class="field-validation-error" style="display:none">It's not red.</span>

var url = '@Url.Action("CheckStringIsRed", "yourController")';
$.('.validatecolor').blur(function() {
    $.getJson(url, { color: $(this).val() }, function(result) {
        if(!result) {
            $(this).next('span').show(); // choose a better relative selector :)
        });
    });
});
```

and change the controller method parameter to `string color`